# How to split 2 columns with patterns?

Tags: python, pandas, string, split, data-cleaning

I have a dataset (df) with 2 columns of arbitrary length, and I need to split it up based on the value.

| BUS | CODE |
| --- | --- |
| 150 H.S.London-lon3 11£150 H.S.London-lon3 16£150 H.S.London-lon3 120 | GERI |
| 400 Airport Luton-ptr5 12£400 Airport Luton-ptr5 15£400 Airport Luton-ptr5 17 | 24£JTR |
| 005 Plaza-cata-md6 08£005 Plaza-cata-md6 012£005 Plaza-cata-md6 18 | 78£TDE |

I've been trying to split it to look like this:

| bus | directions | zone | time | code | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 150 | H.S.London | lon3 | 11 | NaN | GERI |
| 400 | Airport Luton | ptr5 | 12 | 24 | JTR |
| 005 | Plaza-cata | md6 | 08 | 78 | TDE |

So far, I tried to split by patterns, but isn't working and I'm out of ideas or how to split it in other way.

```
bus = '(?P<bus>[\d]+) (?P<direction>[\w\W]+)-(?P<zone>[\w]+)'
code = '(?P<code>[\S]+)£(?P<name>\d+)
df.BUS.str.extract(bus)).join(df.CODE.str.extract(code)
```

I was wondering if anyone had a good solution to this.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with `regex` pattern containing named capturing groups:

```
code = r'^(?P<code>\d+)?.*?(?P<name>[A-Za-z]+)'
bus  = r'^(?P<bus>\d+)\s(?P<directions>.*?)-(?P<zone>[^\-]+)\s(?P<time>\d+)'

df['BUS'].str.extract(bus).join(df['CODE'].str.extract(code))
```

---

```
   bus     directions  zone time code  name
0  150     H.S.London  lon3   11  NaN  GERI
1  400  Airport Luton  ptr5   12   24   JTR
2  005     Plaza-cata   md6   08   78   TDE
```

See the regex demo for `code` pattern [`here`](https://regex101.com/r/NmmJRq/2) and for `bus` pattern [`here`](https://regex101.com/r/uA3o8i/1).

Comment: you are awesome

Comment: That was a big big help.

Answer (score 2):

You could use split:

For your code column:

```
new_cols = ['code','name']

df[new_cols] = df.CODE.str.split(pat = '£', expand = True)
```

Im sure you can find a way to do this for your first column, and if you have duplicates remove them after splitting

Comment: Totally forgot about this. Great help!